# Mac App Store Upload Fail: Validation Error (SFML)

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I'm working on a SFML App in Xcode 7.2, and I'm trying to upload my project build to the Mac App Store, and I'm getting the following error:

> An error occurred during validation
>
> Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for A

I've tried, among other things, adding a new entry to my Info.plist for CFBundleSupportedPlatforms with an entry for OSX. I've tried changing dylibs vs frameworks, i've tried universal vs standard architectures. All of these modifications have yeilded no success.

This question is following a [previous problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219226/freetype-code-signing-error-xcode-7-1-app-upload-issue) with freetype that I fixed. Is it possibly still a problem with freetype? any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
 OK, I've gone through and reset up a whole new project following the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html). I Did see some issues with some of my build settings, and fixed them. But I'm Still getting the same error. Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864559/malformed-freetype-framework-in-sfml-mac-app/20876352#20876352 this question seems to be related to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! 
The problem was that I had only edited my project-info.plist. I went and added the same lines for CFBundleSupportedPlatforms to the info.plist's for each of my external frameworks.

- CFBundleSupportedPlatforms => array,
- item0 => MacOSX

Seems to have done the trick.